# Custom make command for learning

Tags: c, bash

I want to have a make command like this but to which I can pass many arguments and the name of the resulting file is the name of the first one.

It has to accept the name with .c and remove the .c from the source file name for the executable name.

```
# My custom make command
mk() {
    echo "gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror ${1}.c -o $1";
    gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror ${1}.c -o $1 ;
}
```

Something like this maybe?

```
mk() {
    echo "gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror ${@} -o $1";
    output=$1
    set -- "${@/%/.c}"
    gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror ${@} -o $output;
}
```

Comment: Why not create a makefile and use that?

Comment: I would have to create it for every exercise.

Comment: Really?  I have a single makefile in my SOQ (Stack Overflow Questions) directory which I use to compile any program I choose without editing the makefile.  Granted, I type `make newprog43` (specifying the executable, not the source file), but it compiles `newprog43.c` into `newprog43` with all my default compiler options, which I can tune if I need to with extra command line arguments.

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Answer (score 5):

You can write a `Makefile` which will allow you to create multiple targets with a single rule.

In fact, building a `<FOO>` from `<FOO>.c` is something for which `make` has a predefined rule, so you can create a Makefile with

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror
```

and then run `make bar`.

As long as there is a file named `bar.c`, `make` will build it for you.

Comment: And in fact, you can take this a step further: `make` does not require any Makefile at all if it can rely on a built-in rule to build the requested target from an available source.  I use it that way fairly frequently.  But the Makefile does provide a handy place to record commonly-used options for reuse.

Comment: I think OP wanted to build a single program from several source files, which this snippet will not do.

Comment: @IanAbbott The OP did tag bash. If he is working in a linux environment, he could probably make a link to the makefile so all he has to do is make, and the makefile can be referenced to attempt the build with.

Comment: @Jouster500 I mean OP's question says something like passing foo.c bar.c baz.c to build program foo. A "generic" makefile rule won't work for that. It would need a specific makefile rule.

Comment: @IanAbbott He wanted a `mk()` function that would allow him to do `mk foo.c` to produce `foo` from `foo.c` (for any `foo`). I have written an answer which (while not technically providing exactly what OP asked) actually helps them achieve what they wanted with minimal effort and a standard tool for this kind of things.

Comment: To quote from the question: "to which I can pass many arguments and the name of the resulting file is the name of the first one". I read that as the "many arguments" being many .c files and the "resulting file" being the resulting executable.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, bash has a way to remove suffix patterns (like `.c` for example):

```
mk() {
    SOURCE="$1"
    DEST="${1%.c}"
    echo "gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror ${SOURCE}.c -o $DEST";
    gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror "${SOURCE}.c" -o "$DEST" ;
}
```

You should learn to use make properly anyway, but that's no reason you can't *also* learn bash.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `makefile` — probably one like [Honza Remeš](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5872193/honza-reme%c5%a1) suggests in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50953005/15168), or a somewhat more complex one like this, which is closely based on what I use when working on Stack Overflow questions.  It allows me to configure which compilation options are used with great granularity.  This is probably overkill for you at the moment — Honza's version is a good starting point — but you may eventually get fussy enough for this to be of benefit.

```
CC     = gcc
DFLAGS = #-DHAVE_CONFIG_H
GFLAGS = -g
IFLAG1 = #-I${INCDIR}
IFLAG2 = #-I${HOME}/inc
IFLAGS = #${IFLAG1} ${IFLAG2}
OFLAGS = -O3
SFLAGS = -std=c11 # -pedantic
UFLAGS = # Set on command line
WFLAG1 = -Wall
WFLAG2 = -Wextra
WFLAG3 = -Werror
WFLAG4 = -Wmissing-prototypes
WFLAG5 = -Wstrict-prototypes
WFLAG6 = #-Wold-style-declaration   # Strict GCC only (not clang, it would seem).
WFLAG7 = #-Wold-style-definition    # Part of -Wextra in GCC 7.1.0
WFLAGS = ${WFLAG1} ${WFLAG2} ${WFLAG3} ${WFLAG4} ${WFLAG5} ${WFLAG6} ${WFLAG7}

LDFLAG1 = #-L${LIBDIR}
LDFLAG2 = #-L${HOME}/lib/64
LDFLAGS = ${LDFLAG1} ${LDFLAG2}
LDLIB1  = #-l${SOQBASE}
LDLIB2  = #-l${CS50BASE}
LDLIBS  = ${LDLIB1} ${LDLIB2}

CFLAGS   = ${OFLAGS} ${GFLAGS} ${DFLAGS} ${IFLAGS} ${SFLAGS} ${WFLAGS} ${TFLAGS} ${UFLAGS}

DEBRIS = core a.out *~ *.o
RM_FR  = rm -fr
RM_F   = rm -f

default:
        @echo "You must specify a target to build"

#all:
# ...rules for what to do for 'make all'

# Provides target 'clean' to do sensible cleaning.
# Relies on user to set macro PROGRAMS (plural) for removing programs.
# OUTFILES can be set per makefile to hold output file names that should
# be cleaned.  OUTDIRS can be set per makefile to hold output directory
# names that should be cleaned.
# .dSYM directories are an artefact of building single-file programs on
# .Mac OS X (or using dsymutil).

.DEFAULT:
    @echo "No commands specified for building $@"

clean:
    ${RM_F} *.o *.a ${DEBRIS} ${OUTFILES}
    ${RM_F} ${PROGRAMS}
    ${RM_FR} *.dSYM ${OUTDIRS}
```

The `UFLAGS` option, in particular, is one I use for 'user flags' — something that I want to add to a particular compilation.  I could use:

```
make UFLAGS="-Wshadow -Wpointer-arith" newprog53
```

to add the extra warning options `-Wshadow -Wpointer-arith` to the compiler command line.

You can find the full version of this makefile in three files:

- `makefile`
- `etc/soq-head.mk`
- `etc/soq-tail.mk`

in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

```
mk() {
    output="${1%.c}"
    echo "gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror ${@} -o $output";
    gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror ${@} -o $output;
}
```